# Brushed on wrong layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, brush, painting

In Photoshop, I accidentally painted some brush strokes on the wrong layer. The thing is, the brush stokes are all captured in the history. Is there some way of restoring those brush stokes to a different layer?

I've seen some methods based on the difference in colours between what you've just painted and the rest of that layer, but I'd prefer a method based on the history states if that's possible.

Comment: No you can not do this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can implement the "butterfly effect" `:)`

While it is possible to use history in a non-linear fashion, to the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to *change what was done* in the history - i.e. alter which layer had pixels applied to it.